# Aligning an address forward

Tags: c++

Im reading this custom memory manager article on gameDev https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/c-custom-memory-allocation-r3010/
and they have a method to foward-align an address. However, I just dont understand it

```
inline void* alignForward(void* address, u8 alignment) 
{
      return (void*)((reinterpret_cast<u8*>(address) + static_cast<u8>(alignment-1)) & static_cast<u8>(~(alignment-1)));
}
```

Here's how the author explains it. "To n-byte align a memory address x we need to mask off the log2(n) least significant bits from x. Simply masking off bits will return the first n-byte aligned address before x, so in order to find the first after x we just need to add alignment-1 to x and mask that address."

I understand why you need to mask off the log2(n) least significant bits. However, the method doesnt work. I have tried it by hand with several number. For exam, if address is 17(in decimal) and alignment is 6(in decimal) the method should return 18, but it doesn't. Perhaps because I dont understand why the author is using u8(which is unsigned char from what I read on the internet) for alignment. Wouldn't it be more intuitive to use int for alignment?

Comment: Further more, the left operand of `&` is an `u8*` (the result of `u8*`+`u8`) and its right operand is an `u8`. If I were a C++ compiler I'd reject that code.

Comment: The formula to align a number to a power of 2 is much more efficient than the general formula to align a number to an arbitrary number. Given that memory alignment is always a power of 2, then it make sense to use the optimized version. Arbitrary alignement would require essentially an addition, a multiplication and a division and division is usually a relatively slow operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alignment is always a power of 2 in C and C++. There are a bunch of bit twiddleing techniques that only work if the alignment is a power of 2.

What the function does is basically add `alignment - 1`, and then round down to the next multiple of alignment. All multiples of the alignment will have their last `log2(alignment)` bits as 0 (Since it is some power of 2) and the mask just sets the last few bits to 0.

Comment: Hi, why would they use u8 though? Is there a reason for it? Also, for my example above, you would do & operator between 22(10110 in binary) and ~5(10 in binary), which would get you 10(2 in decimal), but we want 18. The only way to get 18 is that we keep the first 3 bits unchanged. Sorry for the long explanation, Im  new to this and very confused.

Comment: @HarryKane Since `alignment` looks like `1000...` (So your example doesn't work, as 6 is not a power of 2) in binary, `alignment - 1` will look like `1111...`. `~(alignment - 1)` will look like `..111100000...` (Flips the bits), and if you `&` it, it will basically zero out the rightmost bits.

`u8` is technically wrong. It should be `std::size_t`, like what [`alignof(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) returns. But the maximum is usually 8 or 16, for a long double, which can be held in a `u8` (Maximum is 255 in a u8)